# How to serialize empty list with JAXB as tag with empty body

Tags: java, soap, feign

I use feign to communicate via soap with service hosted by external company. I have definition of collection as below which is generated based on wsdl file:

```
@XmlElement(name = "someName", nillable = true)
protected List<String> someName;
```

And when I send request with empty list, I receive empty tag in the body like:

```
<someName />
```

Is it possible to configure feign/JAXB or create some adapter to get this collection in this way:

```
<someName></someName>
```

Comment: Why do you want to do that? They are synonyms and the one you have will only make the file size larger. What am I missing?

Comment: I know, but unfortunately I don't have any control over this external service, and when I send empty tag like <sameName/> I receive error from it and the company which is responsible for it told me that I have to send collections in way which I descibed.

Comment: That is not a good decision on their part. Are you creating the classes manually or compiled from a schema?

Comment: I generated classes from wsdl but I'am able to change definition of any class, but whatever I tried always I received construction with <sameName />

Comment: have you tried `nillable=false`? I wonder if there's a difference between a null list and an empty list.